# Envoy dynamic configuration from filesystem, multiple path for config

Tags: yaml, envoyproxy

I would like to define multiple path for [dynamic resources](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/start/quick-start/configuration-dynamic-filesystem#dynamic-resources), like this:

```
node:
  id: id_1
  cluster: test

dynamic_resources:
  cds_config:
    - path: /root/envoy/dynamic_fs/cds_ssh.yaml
    - path: /root/envoy/dynamic_fs/cds_https.yaml
    - path: /root/envoy/dynamic_fs/cds_db.yaml
  lds_config:
    - path: /root/envoy/dynamic_fs/lds_ssh.yaml
    - path: /root/envoy/dynamic_fs/lds_https.yaml
    - path: /root/envoy/dynamic_fs/lds_db.yaml
```

I read the official envoy documentation, didn't find a solution. It is possible to achieve something like this? If config is big, with two yaml it's hard to read.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot.  You can read in the [docs](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/config/bootstrap/v3/bootstrap.proto#envoy-v3-api-msg-config-bootstrap-v3-bootstrap-dynamicresources) that CDS, LDS, and ADS only accept a single source of config.